# undefied reference to function in android studio using swig

Tags: java, c++, swig

I am trying to build native android application example using android studio 2.3, but stuck at a point. The code of the project is as follows

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.angelica.testfive;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    static {
        System.loadLibrary("summer");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Example of a call to a native method
        TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.sample_text);
        tv.setText(summer.getSum(2,10).toString());
    }


}
```

**summer.h**

```
#ifndef TESTFIVE_SUMMER_H
#define TESTFIVE_SUMMER_H

#ifdef __cplusplus
#define EXTERN extern "C"
#else
#define EXTERN
#endif

EXTERN char* getSum(int a, int b);
#endif //TESTFIVE_SUMMER_H
```

**summer.cpp**

```
#include "summer.h"
#include <stdio.h>

char* getSum(int a, int b) {
    int result = a + b;
    char szResult[100];
    sprintf(szResult, "The Sum is : %d", result);
    return szResult;
}
```

**CMakeList.txt**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4.1)

add_library(summer           
             SHARED             
             src/main/cpp/summer.cpp )

add_library(summer_wrap
             SHARED
             src/main/cpp/summer_wrap.cxx )


find_library(log-lib
              log )

target_link_libraries(summer_wrap
                       ${log-lib} )
```

I am using swig to generate the .java wrapper for my c++ code.

```
swig -c++ -java -package com.example.angelica.testfive summer.i
```

files generated are as follows:

```
summer_wrap.cxx
summer.java
summerJNI.java
```

Upto here everything is going good as per my knowledge if i am not wrong/maybe.

But when i click debug app in the android studio ide. following error is generated.

[image: gradle build]

this error is really messing me up. I know i am really forgetting something really important but i am unable to figure it out on my own.

Comment: `target_link_libraries(summer, summer_wrap)`?

Comment: @JosephThomson still facing same issue. I am certain i am doing it wrong

Comment: Sorry. I meant the other way around. Try adding `summer` to the list of libraries for `summer_wrap`. The issue is that `summer_wrap` cannot find the function `getSum`, which means the linking/exporting is failing somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that the error is caused by you declaring `getSum` as `EXTERN` but defining it without that linkage class applied. Either drop that part of the declaration or add it to the definition should resolve this issue.